# Threadsafe Events using memory barriers

Tags: c#, .net, events

In the following article Stephen Cleary gives us advice about how to make threadsafe events:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37474/Threadsafe-Events.aspx

The author explains in solution #2 why the following code is wrong:

```
MyEventHandler myEvent = this.MyEvent;
if (myEvent != null)
{
    myEvent(this, args);
}
```

The copy of the event delegate may be out-of-date. Stephen provides the following solution to that problem.

> Without going into a painful level of detail, in order to ensure that
>   one is reading the current value of a non-volatile field, one must
>   either issue a memory barrier or wrap the copy operation within a lock
>   (and it must be the same lock acquired by the event add/remove
>   methods).

I am interested in the details he unfortunately doesn't explain. What does technically happen when using a memory barrier here and what is the difference towards the above approach?

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the code you posted is that the read of the `this.MyEvent` field may be reordered by the compiler/jitter/cpu, and be moved back in time. In other words, you may see a cached value that was read moments before.

In order to prevent this reordering, you issue a memory barrier (aka full memory fence), that tells all 3 participants not to move *any* instructions above (or below) the fence. This will prevent the read from being cached, or from being "merged" with other earlier reads.

```
Thread.MemoryBarrier();

//--> no instructions can be moved above or below the fence <--

MyEventHandler myEvent = this.MyEvent;
if (myEvent != null)
{
    myEvent(this, args);
}
```

Also, notice the date on that blog post, it's quite old.
Events have been re-written since then in the release of C# 4.0.

Stephen Cleary's premise that events are implemented using `lock (this)` is no longer true. Events are now lock-free. You can see this detailed here by Chris Burrows: [Events get a little overhaul in C# 4, Part I: Locks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/05/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-i-locks.aspx).

You may also be interested in reading the other 3 parts of this series:

- [Events get a little overhaul in C# 4, Part II: Semantic Changes and +=/-=](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/08/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-ii-semantic-changes-and.aspx)
- [Events get a little overhaul in C# 4, Part III: Breaking Changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/18/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-iii-breaking-changes.aspx)
- [Events get a little overhaul in C# 4, Afterward: Effective Events](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/30/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-afterward-effective-events.aspx)

Comment: yeah, this is already mentioned in the article. But i am interested in the details. What is the reason, a  cached value may be returned and what exactly does the memory barrier?

Comment: @GinoBambino I thought I made it pretty clear... by default, the compiler/jitter/cpu are allowed to reorder instructions as they see fit (although there are a few restrictions). By introducing a memory barrier, you tell them *not* to reorder any instructions above/below the fence. This will prevent the value from being cached.

Comment: @GinoBambino does that answer your question?

Comment: @GinoBambino Ive also updated my answer with how events are implemented from C#4 onwards

Comment: Sorry for not giving a response yet and thanks for providing additional information.